# How to start a Process from resources?

Tags: c#, process, resources, skype

I want to start skype like pressing Win+R and than typing in the Run task "skype.exe" and this should happen when i just click the Button on the Windows Form.

I just want to start skype by clicking the button but it crash every time.

```
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process X = new Process(); 
        X.StartInfo.FileName = "Skype.exe";        
        X.Start();
        //Process.Start(Properties.Resources.lul);  ||lul is a batch file in the resources which should after running start skype but it doesn´t work :/     
    }
```

Comment: If it's in resources, you're gonna have to save it somewhere temporarily, and then run it, and then delete it again if need be. `Process.Start` requires a path, and your resource file is not a valid path.

Comment: Please specify what exception do you get. And i don't think that has something to do with resources or with a skype.

Comment: I want to start skype like pressing Win+R and than typing in the Run task "skype.exe" and this should happen when i click the Button on the Windows Form.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah finaly i get it on my own -.-
i

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\Skype.exe");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

A FileName is not just the name of the exe, but also the path to it.
Here is the [standard microsoft example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();

        try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
            // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
            // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
            // from this application using the Kill method.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```